# Trouble using .not() to limit options after being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problems

### Update #1: Clarification

a) I'm trying to make it so that when a person clicks `<p class=rect G1>Male</p>`, they are unable to choose female option, `<p class=rect G2>Female</p>` unless their first option is clicked again and deselected. I've been using .not(), but they are still both selectable.

b) With the ethnicity category, I want the user to be able to select two things for example, "White" and "Black" before being unable to make another selection.

### scripts.js

```
// Numbers
var total = 56
var male = 41;
var female = 15;

// Option #1: Gender
$( ".G1" ).click(function() {
    $(".headshot").not(".Female").toggleClass("show");
    $(".number").html(total - female);
});

$( ".G2" ).click(function() {
    $(".Female").toggleClass("show").not(".Male");
    $(".number").html(total - male);
});
```

### index.html

```
   <section class="selection">
                <div class="gender">
                    <p class="category">Gender</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect G1">Male</p>
                        <p class="rect G2">Female</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.gender -->

                <div class="age">
                    <p class="category">Age</p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect A1">Under 35</p>
                        <p class="rect A2">36-64</p>
                        <p class="rect A3">65+</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.age -->

                <div class="ethnicity">
                    <p class="category">Ethnicity<span>*<span></p>
                    <div class="options">
                        <p class="rect E1">White</p>
                        <p class="rect E2">Black</p>
                        <p class="rect E3">Aboriginal</p>
                        <p class="rect E4">Metis</p>
                        <p class="rect E5">Asian</p>
                    </div><!-- /.options -->
                </div><!-- /.ethnicity -->
            </section>

            <img src="assets/img/headshots/wiebe.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Male White">
            <img src="assets/img/headshots/wight.jpg" alt="" class="headshot NDP Female White">
            <img src="assets/img/headshots/wishart.jpg" alt="" class="headshot PC Male White">
```

### chart.scss

```
.Male, .Female,
.Low, .Middle, .High,
.White, .Black, .Aboriginal, .Metis, .Asian  {
    @include transitions;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

// Toggle class for when MLAs selected
.show {
    @include transitions;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I see no `headshot` class in the HTML.

Comment: @Jacob I've added a snippet of the images with the classes of "headshot" in the bottom of my `index.html`in the example.

Answer (score 0):

`not` only limits the selection, which means you have to use it before the `toggleClass` call.

In other words, your code should be:

```
$(".Female").not(".Male").toggleClass("show");
```

... although it seems odd that your ".Female" elements would also be ".Male" ... perhaps you should just remove the `not(".Male")` bit entirely? Also, in the HTML you provided there is no "Male" or "Female" class on any of the elements. Just because the elements have the text "Male" in them won't make them have a class of "Male"; to do that you need to add a class attribute such as `class="Male"` to the element (or in your case, `<p class="rect G1 Male">Male</p>`.

Also, jQuery comes with `show` and `hide` methods which you can use instead of `toggleClass("show")`.

Finally, your code references a `total` variable, but there's no mention of it in the code you included.

**EDIT**

To sum things up, what you want is HTML like this:

```
<p class="rect G1 male">Male</p>
<p class="rect G2 female">Female</p>
```

Then to (for instance) disable the "female" div you would use a bit of jQuery like:

```
var $femaleDiv = $('.female'); // select the div with class "female"
$femaleDiv.prop('disabled', 'disabled'); // add a disabled property
```

Or to shorten it:

```
$('.female').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

However, that won't work on `<div>`s, because they aren't form controls. So, let's pretend you actually have radio buttons in those divs, or in other words let's pretend your HTML is:

```
<p class="rect G1 male">Male <input type="radio"/></p>
<p class="rect G2 female">Female <input type="radio"/></p>
```

Then you can disable the *inputs* with the following code (almost the same as before):

```
var $femaleRadio = $('.female :input'); // select the radio in the "female" div
$femaleRadio.prop('disabled', 'disabled'); // add a disabled property
```

Or to shorten it:

```
$('.female :input').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I've changed it to `$(".Female").not(".Male").toggleClass("show");` but unfortunately, I can still select both options

Comment: As I suggested try removing `.not('.Male')` (it's redundant) and changing `toggleClass("show")` to `hide()` and finally add the "Male" class in the HTML.

Comment: Of course, that assumes you truly want to hide the div; if you just want to disable the input you'll want to add a "disabled" attribute to it instead.

Comment: It's less about hiding the div, it's more about just making the user unable to click a second option, if they've clicked a first one. How do I add a disabled attribute?

Comment: The general idea is that 1) you mark elements with classes (eg. `class="Male"`), 2) select elements that you marked using jQuery (eg. `$('.Male')`), 3) then you call an operation on your selection (eg. `$('.Male').hide()`). Or if you want to disable instead `$('.Male').prop("disabled", "disabled")` (and `$('.Male').prop("disabled", "")` to reenable).

Comment: Could you update your answer so that I can see the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your classes in jQuery do not reflect your classes in HTML.

Add female and male to the HTML:

```
  <p class="rect G1 male">Male</p>
  <p class="rect G2 female">Female</p>
```

And remove not:

```
$('.g1' ).click(function() {
    $('.g2').toggleClass("show");

    $(".number").html(total - female);
});

$('.g2').click(function() {
    $('.g1').toggleClass("show");
    $(".number").html(total - male);
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem as both options are still able to be selected at the same time.

Comment: Missed your intention. Should be fixed with my changes.